# How do I check a PTR record?

Tags: email, spam, ptr-record

I need to check a PTR record to make sure that a script I have is sending emails which will actually be received by my users and not be incorrectly marked as spam.

I understand that the ISP which owns the IP range has to set up the PTR record, but how do I check if it is already set up?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you have **Unix or Linux**, you can do this by typing this on a command prompt:

```
dig -x xx.yy.zz.aa
```

You'll get an answer with your authority of aa.zz.yy.xx.in-addr.arpa and server resolving to this address.

In **Windows** you can do `nslookup xx.yy.zz.aa`.

You can also check **online** at [**www.intodns.com**](http://www.intodns.com) and input your domain... It will error on the results checking for a reverse zone lookup.

*xx.yy.zz.aa = The IP address you're trying to resolve*

---

**Update:**

> When using dig, nslookup, or host it is frequently useful to use a DNS server outside of your control like Google (8.8.8.8) so you get confirmation things are right from a 3rd party. – [**Zoredache**](https://serverfault.com/users/984/zoredache)

[**Zoredache**](https://serverfault.com/users/984/zoredache)  makes a good point. Here are the commands for testing/resolving to external/outside DNS servers:

Dig (testing reverse DNS on Google's DNS server of 8.8.8.8):

```
dig -x zz.yy.xx.aa @8.8.8.8
```

Host and Nslookup (testing reverse dns on Google's DNS server of 8.8.8.8)

```
nslookup zz.yy.xx.aa 8.8.8.8
host zz.yy.xx.aa 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: When using dig, nslookup, or host it is frequently useful to use a DNS server outside of your control like Google (8.8.8.8) so you get confirmation things are right from a 3rd party.

Answer (score 23):

I know this has been marked as answered but I want to provide a more comprehensive answer. For my examples I will be using:

1. **google.com**'s IP address *172.217.3.206* because it **does** have a
   PTR record.
2. **serverfault.com**'s IP address *151.101.1.69* because it **does not** have a PTR record.

The first thing to note is `dig` is a  multiplatform command, you can get it for Windows on the [ISC BIND website](https://www.isc.org/downloads/) listed under BIND, then select your Windows platform (32 or 64 bit). It has many other tools including its own nslookup binary. I don't use that nslookup.exe version, instead I use the default one that comes with Windows (C:\Windows\System32\nslookup.exe). However if you want to use `dig` you may want to edit your local PATH environment variable, or move the `dig` tool to your C:\Windows\System32 folder.

Command 1) `dig PTR 206.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa` - Traditionally this is how a user would perform a reverse DNS lookup. They would manually transpose the IP address: `172.217.3.206` to `206.3.217.172` (notice the order of each of the four octets) and add `in-addr.arpa` to the end of the string. Here is the output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5 <<>> PTR 206.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39790
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;206.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
206.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 84300 IN    PTR     sea15s12-in-f206.1e100.net.
206.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 84300 IN    PTR     sea15s12-in-f14.1e100.net.
206.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 84300 IN    PTR     sea15s12-in-f14.1e100.net.
206.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 84300 IN    PTR     sea15s12-in-f206.1e100.net.

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 26 04:20:28 Pacific Daylight Time 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 153
```

Command 2) `dig -x 172.217.3.206` - This version of the command is a lot simpler, as described in the `dig -h`, the `-x` flag is a "shortcut for reverse lookups". The output is identical to the output shown above in the previous command.

Command 3) `dig -x 151.101.1.69` - This example is showing what it looks like when a PTR record is not found, using the serverfault.com example. As you can see, the answer does not list a PTR, and can only find the SOA record of `151.in-addr.arpa`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5 <<>> -x 151.101.1.69
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 21854
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;69.1.101.151.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
151.in-addr.arpa.       1786    IN      SOA     pri.authdns.ripe.net. dns.ripe.net. 1490512027 3600 600 864000 3600

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 26 04:30:38 Pacific Daylight Time 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 114
```

Command 4) `nslookup 172.217.3.174` - This is the command suggested by user [l0c0b0x](https://serverfault.com/users/1840/l0c0b0x) in the primary answer on this thread. While it is true that there is a result, it is not clear if this is a PTR record or some other type of record. I think it does by default return a PTR if it is given an IP, but I still want to be sure. It also omits other records if there are multiple PTRs:

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Name:    sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net
Address:  172.217.3.174
```

Command 5) `nslookup -debug 172.217.3.174` - Use this command instead to see the full list, including the record type and the full list of results. The `-debug` flag persists, to turn it off you must use `-nodebug`:

```
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa
        name = google-public-dns-a.google.com
        ttl = 86141 (23 hours 55 mins 41 secs)

------------
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 4,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa
        name = sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net
        ttl = 83026 (23 hours 3 mins 46 secs)
    ->  174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa
        name = sea15s11-in-f174.1e100.net
        ttl = 83026 (23 hours 3 mins 46 secs)
    ->  174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa
        name = sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net
        ttl = 83026 (23 hours 3 mins 46 secs)
    ->  174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa
        name = sea15s11-in-f174.1e100.net
        ttl = 83026 (23 hours 3 mins 46 secs)

------------
Name:    sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net
Address:  172.217.3.174
```

Command 6) `nslookup -type=PTR 172.217.3.174` - This version of the command specifies PTR records with the `-type` flag. It is different than the version without the `-type` flag in two ways. The first is it lists all PTR answers. The second is that it includes the information "Non-authoritative answer" which the other command neglects to include. If you carefully look above at the debug output, the `authority records` state 0, so both of these commands should state  "Non-authoritative answer".

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa      name = sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net
174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa      name = sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net
174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa      name = sea15s11-in-f174.1e100.net
174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa      name = sea15s11-in-f174.1e100.net
```

Command 7) `nslookup -debug -d2 -type=PTR 151.101.1.69` - Here is how you would get as much detail as possible about the full reverse lookup request. Reminder: To turn it off use `-nodebug` and `-nod2`. This example is purposely failing on the serverfault.com example:

```
------------
SendRequest(), len 38
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (82 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa
        type = PTR, class = IN, dlen = 32
        name = google-public-dns-a.google.com
        ttl = 86280 (23 hours 58 mins)

------------
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

------------
SendRequest(), len 43
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  query, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        69.1.101.151.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer (103 bytes):
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        69.1.101.151.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  151.in-addr.arpa
        type = SOA, class = IN, dlen = 48
        ttl = 1787 (29 mins 47 secs)
        primary name server = pri.authdns.ripe.net
        responsible mail addr = dns.ripe.net
        serial  = 1490512027
        refresh = 3600 (1 hour)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 864000 (10 days)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find 69.1.101.151.in-addr.arpa.: Non-ex
istent domain
```

Command 8) `nslookup 174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa` - You may be wondering if you can use the traditional reverse DNS lookup method with `nslookup` as we did in Command 1 with `dig`. You can. Notice the same nslookup failings as I listed above (Command 6) between this command and the one with the `-type=PTR` flag set below (Command 9):

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Name:    174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa
```

Command 9) `nslookup -type=PTR 174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa` - As you may expect, it looks identical to Command 6.

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa      name = sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net
174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa      name = sea15s11-in-f14.1e100.net
174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa      name = sea15s11-in-f174.1e100.net
174.3.217.172.in-addr.arpa      name = sea15s11-in-f174.1e100.net
```

Comment: No problem, I think I'm still missing some knowledge about the meaning and significance of authority as it relates to the output. I'll do some research and add it when I'm done.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I encourage the OP to mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as doing any kind of DNS lookup.

From a windows command prompt: `nslookup.exe <ip address>`

From a linux command line: `host <ip address>`

Note: It is probably best to run these commands from a computer outside of your network, so that you are accessing a public DNS server. Alternatively, both nslookup and host offer ways to specify the DNS server to use.

Answer (score 1):

For the IP V4 example on `1.1.1.1` you can try these on Linux to get the name from the IP.

```
dig -x 1.1.1.1
```

Or

```
nslookup 1.1.1.1
```

Or

```
host -t PTR 1.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Intro:

(2) examples, one for IPv4 and the other for IPv6.
The IPv6 PTR lookup procedure took me ages to find an answer to...

## IPv4:

We'll use Google's IP for the IPv4 example:

```
host -t PTR 209.85.218.49
```

Returns the reverse mapping:

```
49.218.85.209.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer mail-ej1-f49.google.com.
```

## IPv6:

**STEP 1**: Obtain the IPv6 address of the host (usually a mailserver):

```
host -t AAAA mail.yourServer.net
```

This returns the IPv6 address we need for the PTR lookup in the next step:

```
mail.yourServer.net has IPv6 address 2001:340:1c1e:14::2
```

**STEP 2**:Now supply the IPv6 address to the `host` command:

```
host -t PTR 2001:340:1c1e:14::2
```

Returns the IPv6 PTR record:

```
2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.4.1.0.0.e.1.c.1.0.4.3.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa domain name pointer mail.yourServer.net.
```

**NOTE**: the IPv6 address has been anonymized.

Since Hurricane Electric gave me the [FREE IPv6 block](https://tunnelbroker.net/), I set the reverse IPv6 DNS directly in their [DNS control panel](https://dns.he.net/) for mailserver.

## Reverse IPv6 Generator:

Obviously, the above IPv6 PTR record is a bit crazy and being lazy, I just used a reverse IPv6 Generator to create it for my mailserver. There are others, but I used the following to derive the correct value for the reverse IPv6:

https://www.whatsmydns.net/reverse-dns-generator